# Que tipo de excepcion podria poner dentro del catch para evitar errores si se ingresa letras y no se puede realizar la conversion?

Tags: java

```
if (i == 1 && e.getSource() == verificar) {
        String volver = ingreso.getText();///obtiene el texto a partir de una 
         caja de texto
        System.out.println(volver);// esto es solo una verificacion mia
        int numEntero = Integer.parseInt(volver); //intento realizar la conversion--------
        System.out.println(numEntero);
        i++;
```

}

¿Que tipo de excepcion podria colocar dentro de un catch para evitar problemas?

Comment: No entendí nada. ¿Podrías editar la pregunta y agregar con detalles cual es el problema?

Answer (score 1):

Para catpurar errores de conversión de `parseInt` existe la excepción [NumberFormatException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html)

```
try {
    // tu código que puede lanzar una excepción
} catch(NumberFormatException e){
    // aquí lo que quieras hacer con el error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo no se mucho hacerca de codificar y lo que es mas me da un Poco igual pero te puedo simplificar un Poco la exelente explicacion dada por el amigo tan amable solo fijate Los scripts utilizados para cada situaciacion si a ti como a mi se te complica un Poco asocia Los metodos  de tal forma que cada que Los Veas no pienses en como acomodarlos sino en el metodo y a donde te lleva con respecto a lo que estas haciendo y te encuentras desarrollando

Comment: Esto no es una respuesta. Te invito a leer esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.

Comment: No es una respuesta valida. Por favor quitala.

Comment: Todas las respuestas son válidas de acuerdo a lo que hacemos cualquier cosa es válida acuérdate que depende tanto de mí como de ti con todo respeto claro

Comment: @VictorHugoSánchezGracida Tu respuesta no es válida porque no resuelve la pregunta del OP.